Proper way to bundle asynchronous sensor data into one ROS Message
I am trying to generate ROS Odometry Messages from separate data sources.
By "separate" I mean angular and linear measurements arrives asynchronously at random intervals.
Currently, my code composes a new Odometry message upon arrival of any new data (e.g. upon accelerometer data arrival, update location and velocity but leave attitude unchanged. And vice-versa).
This worked fine to some extent, until recently I noticed some lag in my perception renderings which relied on Odometry. Since I already have linear interpolation in my code but it did nothing to the lag, I dug a little deeper and ended up with the following figure:

Each point on the curve indicates an Odometry message.
The red points mean that the attitude is not updated due to lack of angular measurement.
As you can see, simple linear interpolation does not work on the heading curve (it produces the black solid line). The extra red points are preventing my code to correctly map a timestamp into an angular heading. Desired perception should be the dashed green line.
In the demo I generated, I applied an 1-D differential on the curve to filter out all "outdated" data points. However, this is not feasible in real-time applications because you cannot tell if the repeated measurements are "outdated" or if they are just reflecting the true status of a stationary robot.
Here comes my question:
Is there an existing technique to handle this? Can I properly mark part of an Odometry message to be "invalid" (i.e. data is not up-to-date)?

P.S. Since a lot of ROS packages requires sensor_msgs/Odometry as their input, creating a new custom message type will not make them happy. (Refer to: this answer)


No, there is no mechanism to invalidate some fields of an Odometry message.
It seems like a simple predictor that uses velocity would give you better results than your current graphs show. You correct the state when new data arrives.
